# Unexpected cookies in my web applications, what are they?

Tags: php

I keep getting error messages in my PHP error log because my script expects the cookie's value to be a string, but it's getting array values. So I logged the cookies and here's what I got:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 87794,90b4b252c8efee792d9b6396f01c1c34,13,210,1375834294,1,1,1373242294,1,SEO link
)
```

What is this? I got about 15 of these in 10 minutes, all from different referrers. Is this some sort of hacking attempt?

P.S. These were definitely generated by the user, not by my scripts.

Comment: Are you using any third-party software for search engine optimization (SEO)?

Comment: No, I hand coded everything. These cookies aren't appearing on my computer, they're logged from my users.

Comment: They may be from browser extensions or spyware installed on their computers.